# Probability of obtaining a 3 from one die and a 4 from the other under the following three conditions

Tags: probability

I am solving my homework of probability class. I am not sure my approach is correct or not.

The problem consists of three questions:

> Throw a pair of dice at the same time.
>
> 1. If the dice are distinguishable, what is the probability of getting 3 from one die and 4 from another?
> 2. If the dice are not distinguishable, what is the probability of getting 3 from one die and 4 from another?
> 3. If the dice are not distinguishable and the possibility of getting any identical number for the two dice is eliminated, what is the
>    probability of getting 3 from one die and 4 from another?

For Q1, the sample space is $6*6$ and the cases are (3,4) and (4,3), thus the probability is $2/6^2=1/18$.

For Q2, No matter what the dice are distinguishable or not, the probability of the same event is not changed unless a particular die is specified to have a certain value. So, the probability is the same as Q1. => $1/18$

For Q3, the sample space is $6*5$ and the cases are (3,4) and (4,3), thus the probability is $2/(6*5)=1/15$.

Could you check my solution is going right direction?

Comment: The sample space is the major issue here. The sample space of problem 1 is indeed $6\times6$ with each of the same probability. But if the two dices aren't distinguishable (problem 2), the sample space should be $21$ and the probability won't be the same (15+6). In problem 3, the sample space should be $15$ with each of the same probability. So your answers are all correct but the main idea here is about the sample space.

Comment: Thanks @O-17, I understand regarding Q3. But, for Q2, are you saying its answer would be $1/21$? If this is the case, I cannot understand how the probability for getting 3 and 4 of two dices is different in accordance with distinguishability. How does distinguishability affect the probability of the same outcomes?

Comment: I think I get an important insight from from you @O-17. For Q2, the size of sample space is 21 but probability of each elements in this space are not even! For example, the probability of (1,2) is twice that of (1,1). This is the reason why the answer of Q2 is the same of Q1, even though sample spaces of those differ.

Comment: "die" for singular and "dice for plural.

Comment: @ChardLee Right, you get the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have done it correctly.

Even if two dice are indistinguishable the probability of getting 3 from one die and 4 from another will remain same.

we can not distinguish between (3,4) and (4,3) but it does not affect the fact that they can occur in two different ways.

Comment: I suspect that the author of the exercise did not formulate clearly, and his idea for question 1 was : you have 2 dices (Red and Blue), what is the probability to obtain Red=3 and Blue=4 ? But it is only suspicion. Your answer is better quality than the question.